# Any help! Error System IO File Not Found Exception

Tags: c#, bluetooth

When I run this program I have fixed this error.
Any help!

Error
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

```
class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                                    
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Bluetooth bluetooth = new Bluetooth();
        bluetooth.startScan();
    }
    
    class Bluetooth
    {
        Guid mUUID = new Guid("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices;
        public void startScan()
        {             
            Thread bluetoothScanThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(scan));
            bluetoothScanThread.Start();
        }
        public void scan()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start scanning...");
            BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
            devices = client.DiscoverDevicesInRange();
            Console.WriteLine(devices.Length.ToString() + " devices discovered");
            Console.WriteLine("Scan complete");                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.Configuration? Also, the code you have shown does not use it anywhere, at least not directly so showing it does not help.

Comment: Yeah exactly. This code is not using the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` explicitly. I'm not sure if `Bluetooth` as mentioned here is some kind of a library that depends on it

Comment: It seems you may be using another library with using `BluetoothClient`, `BluetoothDeviceInfo`, is this correct?

Comment: @Sangeethnandakumar `Bluetooth` is a class the OP has defined...

Comment: Oh sry I mean the Bluetooth related classes together. May be a typo

Comment: @Codexer This code is running well in case of Gui application, but when I tried to make it a console application it gave me this error, which I had installed System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager from Nuget to solve it, but it gave me another error " Could not load file or assembly System.Windows.Forms " , System.Windows.Forms was a reference in the original Gui application, but here I can't make it a reference.Any Idea!!

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing the dll. Try installing this from Nuget

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
```

Comment: I had installed System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager from Nuget to solve it, but it gave me another error " Could not load file or assembly System.Windows.Forms "

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting the `bin` an `obj` folders, and then clean rebuilding your project.
If that doesn't work (assuming the missing assembly it's in there, but VS is not finding it) you can edit the .csproj file by adding a hint (a route) to the declaration of the assembly.